# Automatic update in wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia

Does Wikipedia has automatic update in anyway?

I mean, yesterday Juventus FC won his 7th Italian Supercoppa, so the Supercuppa page has to be updated with all the info, then the most present players stats has to be update, then the winner player stats has to be updated, then all the single players stats has to be updated and so on.

I believe that making all this update by human can create a forgetfulness

Is there any automatic update o check for this situations?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do such updates automatically, using what on Wikipedia is called [Bots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bots). There are several frameworks you can use to do this, but all require approval by the community first to ensure that the edits the bot is doing is in accordance with policies and guidelines. I am not aware of any specific bots working with soccer statistics, but I could have missed it, there are a lot of different bots running.